# trying to activate a one time discount code

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to give my first-time customers a 10% discount based on the amount in their cart than when they add the amount that passes the threshold the message disappears when they go into their cart.

I have this code so far but literally, I have just started learning PHP this night and am not sure what the next step is. I do not really know where else to go except trying to learn more about PHP. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
$cart = 4167;

$number = ceil($cart / 500) * 500;

echo $number;

$discount = $number - $cart;
$code = "10% off";
echo "\n Spend $$discount more and get $code!";
```

> // Needs to pop up on the first cart entrance

```
function is_first_time() {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['_wp_first_time']) || is_user_logged_in()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        // expires in 30 days.
        setcookie('_wp_first_time', 1, time() + (WEEK_IN_SECONDS * 4), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);

        return true;
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'is_first_time');
```

> // after cart > $number doesnt show up on cart page

I expect the user to get a discount after reaching a threshold based on their cart and then it doesn't show up again.

Comment: in php  $$discount would echo $(value of $discount) https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

I would you use this plugin [Wordpress First Order Discount](https://wordpress.org/plugins/first-order-discount-woocommerce/).

It will make it so if a user signs up to your page and have not ordered before but their cart exceeds a certain value then they can get a discount.

This is the safest way of achieving this as setting a cookie means it can be removed and then customers can gain the discount. By offering 10% off for example for registered customers you are also collecting their email address so you are able to re-market to these customers.

Comment: i have that already, this plug in im trying to code is more a psychological trick so no matter what the cart total is it will round up 500 and tell them if they spend more they can get 10% off with a combination of the 20% they get from signing up for Email on their first visit.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve. 
Can you please explain what conditions need to be set in order to got your outcome.

Comment: so first time user, then the message pops up which rounds their cart to nearest $500 or $1000. takes the difference between the nearest $500 or $1000 and their cart, tells them in the message above the cart "if you spend (difference) than you get 10% off. A person spends the difference and gets 10% off and the message doesn't appear when they go back into their cart.